# Can a variable be treated like an object?

Tags: javascript

This is something which I am confused.

I can define perfectly an object like this :

```
var person = {};
```

and use the dot notation to assign properties, however I have seen a simple definition like this :

```
var person;
```

and then uses

```
person.setName = 'Some cool name';
```

Does Javascript treat it as object even when is not declared as object way ?
Or is that something else?

Comment: No it doesn't, you've missed the assignment code. The value of a declared but unassigned variable is `undefined`.

Comment: If you'd just take a moment to actually test the code you posted, you'd see that it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise that is trivial to test.

Comment: @squint I think is a valid question since in javascript, almost everything is an object, I was confused by now I understand what happens when you skip the object declaration.

Comment: @Rorellanam: you're working with incorrect information. People like to say everything is an object but it's not true. In fact objects are in the minority. There's a single object (or composite) type in ECMAScript and any other object type would inherit from that. Everything else is primitives. Irrespective of that, the question is based on a false premise that is trivial to test. The very first step should have been to actually run your code and see what it does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does Javascript treat it as object even when is not declared as object way ?

An object is a **value**, a variable is a **container** for a value. The *default value* of an uninitialized variable is `undefined`:

```
var person;
// same as
var person = undefined;
```

`undefined` is not an object and cannot be treated as such. The code you posted would throw an error.

```
> var person;
> person.setName = 'Some cool name';
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'setName' of undefined(…)
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, now I got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, setting the `person` like this

```
var person;
```

and then trying to set some property of it will lead to the famous undefined error, because it's just equivalent of

```
var person = undefined;
```

You can't set a property of undefined, because of it not being an object, that's all.